Wrapping a class method in a callable vs an ordinary function
I am trying to decorate class methods. When I use an ordinary function, it works fine. However, when I use a class that implements __call__, it fails for instance level functions despite behaving identically when not used at the instance level. Here is the SSCCE:
import random
class C():
    """A simple class"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.random()

    def report(self):
        return 'The value is: '+str(self.x)
class F():
    """Simulate a function"""
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)

def decoratef(f):
    def f1(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return f1
def decorateF(f):
    def f1(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return F(f1) # This F is the only difference.
report0 = C.report

C.report = decoratef(report0)
print('Test_f0:', C.report(C())) # Works.
print('Test_f1:', C().report()) # Works.

C.report = decorateF(report0)
print('Test_F0:', C.report(C())) # Works.
print('Test_F1:', C().report()) #TypeError: "C.report() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Why is this?

Function objects implicitly implement the descriptor protocol, but classes don't.
By adding an appropriate __get__ method to F you get:
class F():
    """Simulate a function"""
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        def f1(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.f(instance, *args, **kwargs)
        
        return f1

